# Неактивная FloatingActionButton

Tags: java, android

В приложении кнопка полупрозрачна, и при попытке нажать на неё, откликается нижележащее поле, но fab исчезает при прокрутке экрана

[image: Скриншот сделан во время касания кнопки]
Скриншот сделан во время касания кнопки

Пишу в Android Studio

Раздел activity_main:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <requestFocus android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />
    <requestFocus android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#009688"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#4DB6AC"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="#4DB6AC"
        fab:fab_shadow="true"/>
</FrameLayout>


<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.nigga.fuelcontrol.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: попробуйте выставить у кнопки focusable="true" focusableInTouchMode="true" clickable="true"

Comment: Не помогло. =((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К списку в MainActivity был прикреплён id .container
Случайно наткнувшись на нижележащий раздел, я увидел и удалил строчку Placeholder

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что ваш FloatingActionButton располагается под ListView, поэтому и нажатие обрабатывает ListView. Измените ваш layout файл так, чтобы FAB был на верхнем уровне.

Comment: согласен, поменяйте местами в разметке ListView и FAB

Comment: Если вынести FAB из FrameLayout, то он будет отображаться вне него

Comment: В общем, отрисовать FAB поверх ListView у меня получилось (я просто написал FAB ниже ListView). Вот теперь не знаю как сделать так, чтобы и список листался, и кнопка нажималась.
@Roc